# What is the name of the triad with added 6 built on the 5th degree of the Harmonic minor scale

Tags: chord-theory

This would be a major chord with a minor 6 interval. In D minor would such a chord be named Amaj/min6? Is such a chord ever used in music or is it rare? I quite like the sound of it. Sounds dark.

Comment: With "6 chord built on the 5th degree" you mean A, C#, E, F (in d minor)?

Comment: yes that is correct... I would voice the E and F in diff octaves though

Comment: Related question: [Is a minor 6 chord still called that way if the 6 interval is minor?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/64467/is-a-minor-6-chord-still-called-that-way-if-the-6-interval-is-minor).

Answer (score 2):

I would call this an A(b6) adding the parentheses to avoid having it be mistaken for an Ab6, or Ab C Eb F. An “A add b6” is another option.

The fact that it is built from the 5th degree of the harmonic (or melodic) minor is incidental as chord symbols are not tied to any particular scale or key,

Comment: Based on the comment on the OP, maybe include "A add b13" to account for octave displacement?

Comment: aaah ok... so it is just an extension on the dominant chord right? is it a common extension?

Comment: @armani Not a common extension of the major triad, but, as a b13, not an unusual extension of a dominant seventh chord.

Comment: @Aaron b13 would imply an extra octave above the root but as we know in practical use chord symbols don’t indicate any specific voicing. I often voice my 13’s right by the 7th. Since there is nothing other than a triad I prefer the b6 designation personally. Also Armani, you didn’t specify which note would be above or below. If the F is above the E you will have a b9 rub between those notes.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy Agreed. I was referring to armani's comment: "I would voice the E and F in diff octaves".

Answer (score 2):

This is simply an inversion of a seventh chord. A C# E F can more easily be thought of as F A C# E. It is an augmented major seventh chord and yes it is beautiful! A jazz pianist friend of mine (a far better musician than I) has often told me it is his favourite chord!

It doesn’t matter that you have the A in the bass, this doesn’t have to make it some kind of A chord. And it doesn’t matter that it also has an A Major triad in it - by definition, all seventh chords consist of two overlapping triads.

In D Minor, therefore, this is III+7 in first inversion. Or in jazz notation F+maj7/A.

Comment: Nice answer,+1. Generally 6th chords are some type of inversion of a 7th chord and vice versa. Also I’m a big fan of the +maj7 chord myself.